# android inflate exception-ImageView

Tags: android, exception, imageview

I have two activities in which the first one has a button which when clicked should go to the next activity.But when clicked I get the the following error.I have an ImageView whose background is triangular in shape.When I removed the imageview it works fine.

Below is the error:

```
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jobinsabu.destination/com.example.jobinsabu.destination.PickDrop}:android.view.InflateException:  Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class ImageView
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class ImageView
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/triange_shape.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200ce
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2842)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jobinsabu.destination.PickDrop.onCreate(PickDrop.java:14) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: invalid drawable tag vector
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:858)
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jobinsabu.destination.PickDrop.onCreate(PickDrop.java:14) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5326) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
02-25 12:54:20.469 14973-14973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

pick_drop.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#70000000"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"

        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pick"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:text="Pick"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:text="Drop"

            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/triangle1"
            android:background="@drawable/triange_shape"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pick"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/triangle"
            android:background="@drawable/triange_shape"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"></ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Place"
            android:id="@+id/place"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="#9000"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#F50057"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:hint="Pick me here"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#4000"
                android:id="@+id/placedetails"
                android:layout_below="@+id/place"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/placedetails"
                android:id="@+id/pickup_date"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                android:textColor="#F50057"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#9000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#9000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textColor="#F50057"

                 />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/materialedittext1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pickup_time"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
                android:hint="Enter the date"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
               />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/enter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_syle"
            android:text="GET ME THERE"
            android:textColor="#E0E0E0"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pick"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pick" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

triangle_shape(drawable).xml(set as background to image view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100">
<group android:name="triableGroup">
    <path
        android:name="triangle"
        android:fillColor="#FF5722"
        android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,50 -100,0 z"
        android:strokeColor="#FF5722"

        />
</group>
</vector>
```

Java code for PickDrop:
public class PickDrop extends AppCompatActivity {

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pick_drop);

    }
}
```

triangle_shape(edited).xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="220%"
            android:pivotY="70%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#fff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Code for PickDrop class please

Comment: I have included the java code as you asked

Answer (score 0):

please check you ur xml file is in the drawable folder or not?

Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/triange_shape.xml from drawable

Comment: It is in the drawable folder.I have checked it

Comment: c the problem is its not able to find the triange_shape.xml  thats the reason  u r getting problem.

Comment: I have included the screenshot too.. Look into it

Comment: yea i have seen, when you compile the Android System will generate ID for each component and it will store it in  build->generated->src->r->debug->yourpackage->R in this, U r getting exception Resources$NotFoundException with an ID over there no search for that ID in this R.java class if its not there then it din generate ID which means it connot compile triangle_shape.xml file which intern tells the code for triangle shape is wrong. Check once n let me know..

Comment: Do one thing 1)clean the project and check ,if it din work 2) delete that triangle_shape.xml and recreate it again with different name and add as background.

Comment: Tried it, still the same problem.may be it is not the right way to create a triangle.

Comment: If you have a code for creating triangle please share with me

Comment: public static final int trgl_shp=0x7f0200c9; I changed the drawable to trgl_shp.Is this the id?

Comment: 02-25 15:09:31.362 28975-28975/com.example.jobinsabu.destination E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/trgl_shp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c9.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shape tag to create the triangle.

Comment: Question has been edited.Please look into it.I have used shape as you said.But it does not show on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The below link will help you. Use triangleType centerTop and customize the size and color as your requirement.
https://gist.github.com/rsicarelli/770863bc2833b0eab991